# How do I make my router both serve wireless and wired?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have an Actontec MI424WR Rev D Router which is hard wired to my computer and to my printer via the computer. My wife wants to use an Ipad2 in the house wirelessly.  What do I need to do to the router to keep it hard wired as it is and also make it wireless?  The router has 4 100/10 LAN ports and one 100/10 WAN port. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get to the router login page (by typing its ip address in a web browser), login in with the required credentials. Then browse to the wireless section and enable it. I'll have a look at your documentation and try to get you screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

That model appears to have wireless built in. You would have to log into the management interface at [http:\192.168.1.1](http://192.168.1.1). It appears that there is no default username or password, that you must create it when you first log in. If your ISP set this up for you then you will need to go to them to get that information or have them add the wireless functionality. If you do get into the router, these steps are from the [manual](http://www.actiontec.com/support/doc_files/MI424WR_Rev._ACD_User_Manual_4.0.16.1.56.0.10.11.x_v6.pdf):

> To connect a wireless client to the
>   FiOS Router: Note: The following
>   procedure assumes the FiOS Router’s
>   default wireless  settings are intact.
>   If they have been changed, use the new
>   ESSID and wireless  security settings.
>   For more details, see the “Connecting
>   a Wireless Windows XP  Client” section
>   of this chapter. In the wireless
>   client’s configuration interface,
>   enter the FiOS Router’s 
>   1.  ESSID (found on a sticker on the bottom of the FiOS Router’s case) in
>   the  appropriate text box or field
>   (this varies depending on the wireless
>   client’s  manufacturer). Enter the
>   FiOS Router’s WEP key (also found on
>   the sticker on the bottom of 
>   2.  the FiOS Router’s case) in the wireless client’s configuration
>   interface. Save the changes and exit
>   the wireless client’s configuration
>   interface. The 
>   3.  client should now detect and join the FiOS Router’s wireless network. If
>   not,  check the wireless client’s
>   documentation, or contact its
>   manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

It defaults to that mode. Just look on the label for the network name (SSID) and WEP key to use. I recommend you use a web browser to open the router's settings page to set WPA2 security and familiarize yourself with what your router is capable of.